CORS dynamic with Nelmio
I would like to have a dynamic CORS with Nelmio to allow people using my API, and protect from unsafe user.
Ex: in my database I have a list of ORIGIN that's allowed to use it with an X-API-KEY
------------------------------------------
|   id    |     origin      |    api_key  |
------------------------------------------
|    1    | http://test.com |  abcdefgh   |
------------------------------------------

In the .env I put allowed on every request
NELMIO_CORS = "*"

But I added a MiddleWare subscribed to request event on the Kernel, and send to CORS function a list of origin's allowed
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onKernelRequest',
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onKernelException',
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onKernelResponse',
        ];
    }

private function CORS($request, array $allowedOrigins = ['*'])
    {
        
        if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
            if (in_array($request->headers->get('Origin'), $allowedOrigins)) {
                $key = array_search($request->headers->get('Origin'), $allowedOrigins);
                $request->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $allowedOrigins[$key]);
            } else {
                $request->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://fake.net');
            }

            $request->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization');
            $request->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
            $request->headers->set('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
            $request->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        }
    }

The problems are:

If user can fake the request, and dont send OPTIONS method so he can bypass, right ?
What is the best way to do ?


CORS only applies to request from JavaScript in browsers. It doesn't prevent calling your API from other applications. It's meant to protect the client application, not the server.

Okay, say you got a GET or POST request, that also sends an Origin and your X-API-KEY - what is stopping you from applying the exact same validation logic you did for OPTIONS requests, to those as well now?

@Barmar what could i use to prevent from every request ?

@CBroe So, I must to remove the first if condition, and let every single request pass it by ?

Yes, it would make little sense, to be less restrictive for the actual request, than for the preflight request.

@CBroe appreciate mate, have a good day!
